Data validation using a list that depends on another cell
I have an Excel file similar to this:

I would like to create a data validation using a dropdown for the cells E2, F2, G2. I would like the user to insert only the values available in $B2:$B5 filtered by the correct country.
For instance, E2 can contain only {Milan, Naples}
Any idea without using a separate column (for instance, using the filter function)?

Try: =OFFSET($B2:$B5,MATCH(E$1,$A$2:$A$5,0)-1,,COUNTIF($A2:$A5,E$1))

Search for Dependent Dropdown lists. Here is one good resource.

Try using the following formula --> Combination of OFFSET()+XMATCH()+COUNTIF() :


=OFFSET($B2:$B5,XMATCH(E$1,$A$2:$A$5)-1,,COUNTIF($A2:$A5,E$1))


NOTE: If not using Excel 2021 or MS365 then use MATCH() instead of XMATCH(). One more thing this will work as long as the Country column is sorted. 

